Error "ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED" when running TypeScript project with ts-node and ESM
I am trying to run a TypeScript project using ts-node with ESM modules, but I keep encountering the following error:
Error: Package subpath './register/esm' is not defined by "exports" in /path/to/node_modules/ts-node/package.json
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:296:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:643:9)
    ...
    code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'

Command used:
npx ts-node -r ts-node/register/esm app.ts

Environment:

Node.js: v22.11.0
ts-node: v10.9.2
TypeScript: v5.7.2
Operating System: Debian 12 (native and WSL)

What I've tried:

Changing the command to:
npx ts-node --loader ts-node/esm app.ts

Result:
Unknown or unexpected option: --loader


Running with tsconfig-paths:
npx ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register app.ts

Result: The same error persisted.

Updated ts-node and TypeScript to the latest versions, but the problem remains.

Reviewed tsconfig.json, setting "module": "ESNext" and "moduleResolution": "node".


Relevant tsconfig.json section:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}

Question:
How can I run ts-node with proper ESM support? Do I need to adjust any additional settings in tsconfig.json or is there an alternative command that should be used?
Thank you for any guidance or suggestions!
